# Лишние отступы у EditText в разметке

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

Делаю простую разметку: текстовая надпись `TextView`, под ней поле ввода `EditText`. Всё это в `LinearLayout`. Но в результате поле ввода слегка смещено вправо, словно какой-то скрытый margin или padding влияет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если несколько таких надписей и полей ввода, то смотрится некрасиво.

Как убрать это смещение? Ну или как сдвинуть на такое же расстояние TextView, чтобы текст оказался на одном уровне с полем ввода? Не хочу подбирать смещение наугад, т.к. на других версиях Android может всё поехать в другую сторону...

Вот код разметки:

````
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/dialog_item_price_item"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_item_price_item_hint"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp" на EditText. Это фиксированная величина и поэтому проблем на разных устройств не будет.
Либо можно реализовать кастомный background.